# Form Validation - Javascript Remove Space Telephone Number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the script below that checks to make sure a form field for telephone number contains 10 digtis, account for a hyphen and ( ) characters. The issue I have is many times people will put in a telephone number spaced as this - 000 000 0000

When the script is called it throws an error message. How can I use the script below but permit a space in the specified format 000 000 0000 without throwing an error?

Thanks for any help!

```
              function validateTel(telnum) {
              if (telnum.match(/^(1?(-?\d{3})-?)?(\d{3})(-?\d{4})$/)) {
              return true;
              } else {
              return false;
              }
              }
```

Comment: well better set the min and maxlength of your textbox to 10 and dont let user enter anything other than numbers in it, no need of symbols or spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the telephone numbers

```
^\d{3}[ ]{0,1}\d{3}[ ]{0,1}\d{4}$
```

Check the explanation here http://regex101.com/r/iG2fV4

**Sample:**

```
var telRegExp = /^\d{3}[ ]{0,1}\d{3}[ ]{0,1}\d{4}$/;

console.log("1234567890".match(telRegExp))
console.log("123 456 7890".match(telRegExp))
console.log("123 4567890".match(telRegExp))
console.log("123456 7890".match(telRegExp))
console.log("a1234567890".match(telRegExp))
```

**Output**

```
[ '1234567890', index: 0, input: '1234567890' ]
[ '123 456 7890', index: 0, input: '123 456 7890' ]
[ '123 4567890', index: 0, input: '123 4567890' ]
[ '123456 7890', index: 0, input: '123456 7890' ]
null
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using anchors?

```
/^\d{10}$/
```

or may be this regex:-

```
/^\+?\d{2}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{5}$/
```

or may be this regex which will cover most of the cases to validate phone numbers:

```
^(?:\+?\d{2}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{5}|\d{4})$
```

**[Regex Demo](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?340nf)**